# how to disable chrome extension in selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am trying to disable all chrome extensions when starting up my selenium chrome.
But all extensions keep starting up each time I run the code.
Is there a way of disabling the extensions.

### Sample Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "C:\\Users\\ngzhongqin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.cnn.com");
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a fix.

```
  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting capability *chrome.switches* did not work for me (Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m, ChromeDriver 2.18.343845)

Instead using options works:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

or as per [Chrome Driver documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) to set options as capability

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

ChromeDriver(capabilities) is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to set chrome options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
```