# Disable ChromeDriver Extensions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My question is in relation to
[how to disable chrome extension in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049151/how-to-disable-chrome-extension-in-selenium).
What would be the C# equivalent of this? The following is what I've tried so far.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions"));
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Works perfectly for me.