# Selenium WebDriver (Ruby): How to download PDF files?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, plugins, capability

When running WebDriver (**Ruby**) using Chrome, what are the specific **command-line switches** or `desired_capabilities` to disable Chrome's built-in PDF viewer.

In other words, how does one programmatically configure Chrome to download PDF files rather than open using its internal PDF-viewer plugin?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871087/save-pdf-instead-of-opening-in-selenium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated answer: Chrome 61 : Ruby 2.3 : ChromeDriver 2.32.498537

```
      download_prefs = {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        default_directory: 'desired/download/path'
      }

      plugin_prefs = {
        always_open_pdf_externally: true
      }

      options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
      options.add_preference(:download, download_prefs)
      options.add_preference(:plugins, plugin_prefs) 
      driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

Comment: Why do I see `uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options` even if I have `require 'selenium-webdriver'`?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following resource provided [Save PDF instead of opening in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871087/save-pdf-instead-of-opening-in-selenium), I found this worked as desired

```
prefs = {
    plugins: {
      plugins_disabled: ['Chrome PDF Viewer']
    },
    download: {
      prompt_for_download: false,
      directory_upgrade:   true,
      default_directory:   'desired/download/path'
    }
}

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, prefs: prefs
```

There must be **no** trailing slash in the directory path