# C# Selenium Saving pdf page

Tags: c#, selenium

How can I perform the save this page directly in pdf? I know that selenium is not able to control the chrome dialog box ... is there another way?

Page to save in pdf:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way to save is by commanding to the Chrome to save to the disk instead opening to the Page.
Below is the way to do:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
// this will make automatically download to the default folder.
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);  
ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);

var downloadsPath = KnownFolders.Downloads.Path;
var generatedFilePngs = Directory.GetFiles(downloadsPath, string.Format("{0}*.pdf", "TheNameOfYourPDF"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This below code will help to save page as pdf in Selenium c#.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

protected void PDFconversion(ChromeDriver driver, string root, string rootTemp)
{
    //Grid.Rows.Add(TxtBxName.Text, TxtBxAddress.Text);
    try
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        js.ExecuteScript("setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 0);");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string JSPath = "document.querySelector('body>print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('#sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('#destinationSettings').shadowRoot.querySelector('#destinationSelect').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-settings-section:nth-child(9)>div>select>option:nth-child(3)')";
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        IWebElement PrintBtn = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript($"return {JSPath}");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        PrintBtn.Click();
        string JSPath1 = "document.querySelector('body>print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('#sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-button.action-button')";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        IWebElement PrintBtn1 = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript($"return {JSPath1}");
        PrintBtn1.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SendKeys.Send("{HOME}");
        SendKeys.Send(rootTemp + "\\" + "result.pdf"); // Path
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
 
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }

}
```

Comment: Side note : slient catch is not a good practice.

Comment: hi Xoudo ,then please share the code in C# which save page as pdf through chrome in your local pc directly

Comment: You don't have to be upset,: that does not mean your code does not work. (but the empty catch is unnecessary).

Comment: yes its is working fine and leave the catch or modified it as per need, but I need the code in C# which save page as pdf through chrome in your system .....do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

You can directly send the request to the url without Selenium involved and get the byte array with content of PDF file. After that you can read file content using some PDF library (looks like ITextSharp is popular).

Answer (score -1):

Inside Chrome browser all the dialog popups are html pages so you can click on them using Selenium. 
In your case you can navigate to a page, simulate Ctrl + P keyboard button press, switch to print dialog window, click Change button to change the printer, click Save to PDF, click Save button and when "Save As" box is shown - simulate Enter keyboard button press to actually save the file.
I don't do C#, but here is how that looks like in Java, in fact I have tested it and it actually works:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

// get current browser window handles and switch to window with handle that is last in the list
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String handle : windowHandles) {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Change')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Save as PDF')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Save')]")).click();

// you might need to add waiter here that waits a second, since script is too fast
// and needs to wait for save dialog box to be shown

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: What is this robot class? what namespace do I find it in?