# Problems automating getting webpages to .pdf

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the process of downloading webpages with technical documentation which I need to update every year or so.

Here is an example page: http://prod.adv-bio.com/ProductDetail.aspx?ProdNo=1197

From this page, the desired end result would be having all the html links saved as pdf's.

I am using wget to download the .pdf files

I can't use wget to download the html files, because the .html links on the page can only be accessed by clicking through from the previous page.

I tried using Selenium to open the links in Firefox and print them to pdf's, but the process is slow, frequently misses links, and my work proxy server forces me to re-authenticate every time I need to access a page for a different product.

I could open a chrome browser using chromedriver but could not handle the print dialog, even after trying pywinauto per an answer to a similar question here.

I tried taking screenshots of the html pages using Selenium, but could not find out how to get the whole webpage without capturing the entire screen.

I have been through a ton of links related to this topic but have yet to find a satisfying solution to this problem.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Read following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658119/c-sharp-selenium-saving-pdf-page it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Google Chrome-headless browser.

Comment: @SiKing I'm messing around with headless chrome per your suggestion currently. Thought I'd try to use the DevTools Protocol api to printToPDF but of course that uses the same port as chromedriver and I don't think both can be used simultaneously. Going to stick with headless chrome and try to use robot framework to sim keyboard presses for the print dialog per the above linked post