# How to download PDF in previous view (without link) with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pdf, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing a webscraping code to download PDFs automatically from this [site](http://extranet.zetagas.pe/login).

1. You can use the DNI "03972033".
2. After that, click in "Ingresar".
3. Then, click in "FILTROS DE LA TABLA" and select the days between 1-15th October
4. Finally, click in "Filtrar#"

As you can see, there are 4 rows with a PDF file attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2c4t.png)

My code is enough to click in the button and click in "MAYOREO"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqKyN.png)

In that point, I don't know how to download that PDF opened in previous view. There is no a link, there is no buttons. I have no idea.

The button that I want to click with my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Q4N.png)

Can you please give me a hand?

My code is here if you want to see:

```
# 1. Entrando a la página
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(
    ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("http://extranet.zetagas.pe/login")

# 2. Ingresando los DNI

Documentos=driver.find_element(By.NAME,"dni")
Documentos.send_keys("07314752")

# 3. Dandole click a buscar

Buscar=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="submit"]') 
Buscar.click()
time.sleep(5)

# 4. Filtrando por fecha

Filtro=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="accordionFiltrar"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button')
Filtro.click()

# 5. Seleccionando intervalo (ATENCIÓN)

Intervalo = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filtrar_fectras"]')))
Intervalo.click()

    ## 5.1. Ir al mes anterior (solo si es necesario) 

BotonPrev=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="datepickers-container"]/div/nav/div[1]')))
BotonPrev.click()

    ## 5.2 Dándole a los botones de fecha
        #Este es el 1 del mes
Fechainicio=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="datepickers-container"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[7]')))
Fechainicio.click()
        #Este es el 15 del mes
Fechafin=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="datepickers-container"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[21]')))
Fechafin.click()

time.sleep(1)
# 6. Filtrar

Go=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="btn_do_filter"]')
Go.click()
time.sleep(3)

# 7. Entrando a los transportes

    # Seleccionando elementos por clase 'odd' y 'even'
elementos_odd = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'odd')
elementos_even = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'even')

    # Función para verificar si un elemento contiene el texto 'DEVOLUCION' en el XPath específico
def contiene_devolucion(elemento):
    xpath_elemento = elemento.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[12]').text
    return "DEVOLUCION" in xpath_elemento

    # Seleccionar elementos por clase 'odd' y 'even'
elementos_odd = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'odd')
elementos_even = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'even')

    # Combinar los elementos 'odd' y 'even' en una sola lista
elementos_combinados = elementos_odd + elementos_even

    # Filtrar elementos que tienen 'DEVOLUCION' en el campo específico
elementos_con_devolucion = [elemento for elemento in elementos_combinados if contiene_devolucion(elemento)]

    # Identificar y almacenar todos los elementos con la clase 'btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark'
botones_con_devolucion = [elemento.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-outline-dark') for elemento in elementos_con_devolucion]

    # Comando a ejecutar para cada elemento (se ejecutará después de presionar el botón)
def accion_despues_presionar(elemento):
    # Tu código para interactuar con el elemento deseado después de presionar el botón
    time.sleep(1)
    mayoreo=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="printFormato2"]')
    time.sleep(1)
    mayoreo.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #ACÁ DEBERÍA ESTAR LO QUE ME FALTA
    cerrar=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="modalPdfPrint"]/div/div/div[1]/button')
    cerrar.click()
    pass  

    # Iterar sobre los botones con 'DEVOLUCION'
for boton in botones_con_devolucion:
    boton.click()  # Presionar el botón
    accion_despues_presionar(boton)  # Realizar acciones después de presionar el botón
    # Código adicional después de interactuar con el botón (código que falta)
```

A code, idea or related question that shows how to download PDFs opened in Chrome without links with Selenium/Python

Comment: it may need to reconfigure browser to download all files instead of displaying in browser. Eventually you may check if button has link to file and use it directly with module `requests` to download file.

Comment: [google chrome - Save PDF instead of opening in Selenium - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871087/save-pdf-instead-of-opening-in-selenium)