# Java & Selenium : File download automation not working in headless mode with ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I want to download a file from a website in headless mode using Selenium in Java. The code works fine without headless mode and file gets downloaded to downloads folder on the machine. But when I try to use headless mode, the file does not get downloaded somehow. Also, the program does not show any error or exception.

Below is the code. When I comment the statement 'options.addArguments("headless");' , Chrome browser opens the website and clicks the required buttons to download the file. But , I want to use the headless mode only. Please help.

```
File file = new 
                File(StackApplicationDownloader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile()); 
        StackApplicationDownloader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("driver/chromedriver.exe").getFile();
        String driverPath=file.getAbsolutePath(); 
        System.out.println("Webdriver is in path: "+driverPath); 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath); 
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.navigate().to("https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/reports"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"headingTwo\"]/h4/a")).click(); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkCEDailyReport\"]")).click(); 
       System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: Same question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721679/downloading-a-file-from-selenium-and-chromedriver