# Java selenium headless mode download PDF issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless, awtrobot

Below code I have try to download PDF from chrome browser using selenium.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, AWTException, IOException, DocumentException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/sejalj/OtherProj/webDrivers/chromedriver_64");
    ChromeOptions ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    ChromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "window-size=1024,768", "--no-sandbox");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions);

    String baseUrl = "http://url.com/";

    driver.get(baseUrl);

    driver.findElement(By.name("wl_user_name")).sendKeys("uname");
    driver.findElement(By.name("wl_user_password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=Login]")).click();

    String pdfUrl = "https://www.pdfurl.com/displayImageDocs.php?
    f=MjAxODA3MjQxMDUwNzA4Ni5QREY=&p=aW1hZ2UuaW1hZ2ViYW5rLmJsdsaddhbmsxLjIwMTgwNy4yMDE4MDcyNA==&a=MTAwMjM0&POL_NUM=AAS06036999";";

    // Opens pdf of specific URL
    driver.get(pdfUrl);     

    Actions a = new Actions(driver);

    // To press CTRL+S
    a.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("s").build().perform();

    Robot robot = new java.awt.Robot();     
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);     
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
    int keyInput[] = {KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE,
                      KeyEvent.VK_P, KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.VK_L, KeyEvent.VK_I, KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.VK_Y
                     };

    for (int i = 0; i < keyInput.length; i++) {
          robot.keyPress(keyInput[i]);
          robot.keyRelease(keyInput[i]);
    }

    // To press ENTER
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    System.out.println("Preparing Policies document...Please wait");
    System.out.println("Document prepared..");
}
```

Above code working fine while chrome run without `--headless` mode.
But in `--headless` mode above code not working.

`Robot` class does not support in headless mode.
Please guide.

> Solution that has been mark as working can be found here:
>   [Download files in Java, Selenium using ChromeDriver and headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049359/download-files-in-java-selenium-using-chromedriver-and-headless-mode)

Comment: as i'm getting you have direct link of pdf which you want to download..

Comment: try using   `chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);` you can use `hedlesschrome` insted of just `chrome`  Reported Open bug <https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/chimpy/issues/108>

Comment: @PrashantPalve Yes, Actually we have. And we use key events `Ctrl+S` and  `Enter` to save PDF. but in chrome headless mode key event not supporting.

Comment: have you  set any chrome options ?

Comment: @PrashantPalve Yes, `ChromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "window-size=1024,768", "--no-sandbox");`

Comment: @AshishKamble Yes, I have tried `chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);` and headless mode works fine, But I want to download and save PDF in headless mode.

Comment: @AshishKamble I saw that link and trying to implement that solution.

Comment: @Infern0 Yes but solution is not yet available.

Comment: @hrdkisback, i have implemented this at protractor and in headless mode download files, so seem to be working.

Comment: @Infern0 Ok i am still implementing that solution, let me check properly, I will let you know. Thnks.

Comment: @Infern0 thanks for the correct link, I got the solution from that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after referring the below link:
[Download files in Java, Selenium using ChromeDriver and headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049359/download-files-in-java-selenium-using-chromedriver-and-headless-mode)

Here is the working code to download PDF file in headless mode.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, AWTException, IOException, DocumentException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/OtherProj/webDrivers/chromedriver_64");
    
    String downloadPath = "/home/Downloads/AAAA/";
    File file = new File(downloadPath);
    if(!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();
    
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    
    HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();        
    prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);

    chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
    
    String pdfUrl = "https://www.dummyurl.com/prod/displayImageDocs.php?f=MjAxODsafdfgsdjhgsjkA3MjQxMDUwNzA4Ni5QREY=&p=aW1hZ2UuaW1hZ2ViYW5rLmJhbmsxLjIwMTgwNy4yMDE4MDcyNA==&a=MTAwMsgsdjM0&POL_NUM=AAS06036999";
    
    ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions);

    // Saves the file on the given path
    PDFDemo.downloadFile(downloadPath, driverService, driver, pdfUrl);
    logger.debug("File Downloded Start");
        
    long fileSizeOne;
    long fileSizeTwo;

    do {

           File downlodedFolder = new File(downloadPath);
           File downlodedFile = downlodedFolder.listFiles()[0];

           fileSizeOne = downlodedFile.length();
           logger.debug("fileSizeOne " + fileSizeOne);
           Thread.sleep(1500);
           fileSizeTwo = downlodedFile.length();
           logger.debug("fileSizeTwo " + fileSizeTwo);
    } while (fileSizeTwo != fileSizeOne);

    logger.debug("File Downloded Completed");       
    System.out.println("Document Downloaded..");
}

private static void downloadFile(String downloadPath, ChromeDriverService driverService, WebDriver driver, String pdfUrl) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
    commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("behavior", "allow");
    params.put("downloadPath", downloadPath);
    commandParams.put("params", params);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);        
    String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/pdf");
    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
    httpClient.execute(request);

    // Opens pdf of specific URL
    driver.get(pdfUrl);
}
```

Comment: Where you defined the url of file to download ? for example if I click on button download like this, how I can use httpPost ? 


Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("downloadPDF")); 

actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

Comment: After `HttpPost` you need to click that btn, So here you need to put your click btn logic `Actions actions = new Actions(driver); WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("downloadPDF")); actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();` after `HttpPost` instead of `driver.get(pdfUrl);`. So it'll start download the pdf on `downloadPath` location.

Comment: Thanks @hrdkistback, it's working fine!
Curiosity, when the download is large file, and differents times to conclude is 5 min left to finish or 10minute left to finish... How I Can monitoring dynamicly ?The selenium can waiting the downloading finished ?

Comment: @MolinaHenrique I am verifying the downloading complete by comparing file size. Please check my above updated answer. check code after `logger.debug("File Downloded Start");`

Comment: Good solution! hrdkisback thks !!

you already had experienced in Task schedule on Windows server, in which selenium to do download, without the user using it at the moment?
If only set up at options.setHeadless (true); solve this situation?

Comment: Do you mean run chrome in headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and remove  code after `driver.get(pdfUrl);`
         this may help you using HashMap of string with objects,

<-- language: lang-java -->

```
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();        
prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
ChromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Comment: it will download pdf directly instead of open .

Comment: Yes it is working fine when headless mode is false but fail to download when headless mode is set to true.

Comment: okay...what exception it throws? it may be possibility of wait time .

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481, its a bug of chromium already marked...in some cases download was not working in headless mode.

Comment: It does not throw any exception but also not downloading file.