# how to disable chrome pdf viewer in selenium and it should auto download in the default downloads when any pdf occurs

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

i m navigating a website where  i have a situation that when I m clicking on a button it should download the pdf....

I am using the latest version of chrome 60, selenium 3.4, chromedriver.

```
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] {"Chrome PDF Viewer"});
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

I have also used the above code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672897/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-download in firefox browser with java-selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589571/auto-download-in-firefox-browser-with-java-selenium-not-working)

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was adding:

```
chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This just open the Acrobad Reader for me. While it does not open the preview in Chrome it does not skip opening the PDF at all

Answer (score 0):

```
/*ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

/*use to disable the "Chrome is handled by automation script" pop up.*/

options.addArguments("disable-infobars");  

/* use to start the Chrome browser as maximized.*/

options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 

/* HashMap is use to disable the password saving pop up in Chrome browser.*/

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);

prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

/*Download File store in Download folder*/

prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);

prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilesPath);

prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);

HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

options.addArguments("--test-type");

options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); //to disable browser extension 

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);

cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);*
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your post. This is very difficult to understand as it is.

Comment: Code only answers are not as helpful as ones with discussion about why the code will fix the problem. Please edit your answer to add more detail.