# How to disable chrome pdf viewer in new tab with java in playwright

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-options, playwright-java

I'm trying to disable the pdf viewer in a new tab when I use chromium in Playwright. Do you know how can achieve that? Firefox has a method, it's called *.setFirefoxUserPrefs()*.

For chrome, it's not implemented, but found the following thing:
chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments +++ accessible by playwright.
How it can be implemented?

I tried to take know-how from selenium, but for the playwright, it just doesn't work.
I tried:

1. [how to disable chrome pdf viewer in selenium and it should auto download in the default downloads when any pdf occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717426/how-to-disable-chrome-pdf-viewer-in-selenium-and-it-should-auto-download-in-the)
2. [Disabling PDF Viewer plugin in chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877155/disabling-pdf-viewer-plugin-in-chromedriver)

but without any success, can you support me with that?

Including, I tried that:

```
private void PlaywrightSmokeTestConfigureInit(String browserType) {
    playwright = Playwright.create();
    ArrayList<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
    arguments.add("--start-fullscreen");
    
    boolean headless = false;

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("pdfjs.disabled", true);
    map.put("pdfjs.enabledCache.state", false);
    map.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
    map.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
    map.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    map.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
    
    switch (browserType) {
        case "chromium":
            browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setChannel(browserType).setHeadless(headless).setArgs(arguments)
                    .setFirefoxUserPrefs(map));
            break;
        case "firefox":
            browser = playwright.firefox().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setChannel(browserType).setHeadless(headless).setArgs(arguments));
            break; ...
```