# How to read a PDF file opened in browser using Selenium WebDriver Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a task in which a PDF file is generated on clicking a link. My browser settings are such that the file gets opened in a new tab of browser. The browser settings can't be changed as it'll impact other jobs on a daily run.

Is there a way through which we can read the contents of the PDF file opened in the browser in SeleniumWebdriver using Python?

I'm mainly using Chrome or Firefox to automate the task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a pdf file in chrome using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672897/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Also [Selenium Webdriver: How to Download a PDF File with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python)

Comment: @metatoaster My question is about reading the PDF file which is different one from the your suggested ones.

Comment: Or you could search online and you might have [come across this tutorial](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-extract-pdf-text-and-verify-using-selenium-webdriver-java), though you will need to figure out the Python equivalent API calls.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have gone through such methods but I'm unable to find out python equivalent libraries for PDF operations. I guess someone might help me out with that.