# How do I add arguments to ChromeDriver while also using mobile emulation (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using ChromeDriver with my JUnit/Selenium tests. I have tests for both desktop and mobile.

For my *desktop* tests I specify several **Arguments** to ensure test results are consistent, as so:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions desktopOptions = new ChromeOptions();

desktopOptions.addArguments("start-maximized", "disable-extensions",
    "test-type", "no-default-browser-check", "ignore-certificate-errors");

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, desktopOptions);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
```

For my *mobile* tests I currently use:

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Apple iPhone 6");

Map<String, Object> mobileOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mobileOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, mobileOptions);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
```

I can't see a way of including the **Arguments** (such as "disable-extensions") for my mobile tests.

Is there any way I can refactor the mobile method to allow for arguments to be specified?

EDIT: To be a little clearer - I'd like to do something like the below:

```
        Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", deviceType);

        Map<String, Object> mobileOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mobileOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

        ChromeOptions chromeArgs = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeArgs.addArguments("disable-extensions",
                "test-type", "no-default-browser-check", "ignore-certificate-errors");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, mobileOptions);
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeArgs);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
```

But the capabilities overwrite each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a solution =)

(thanks to chromedriver-users google group):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Apple iPhone 6");
Map<String, Object> mobileOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mobileOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

mobileOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList("disable-extensions",
"test-type", "no-default-browser-check", "ignore-certificate-errors"));

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, mobileOptions);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use the setExperimentalOption() method for ChromeOptions

ChromeOptions provides an method [setExperimentalOption(String name, Object value)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setExperimentalOption-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-). This allows you to set a number of options, including the `mobileEmulation` parameters you have set.

Putting your code together, you can use this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized", "disable-extensions",
"test-type", "no-default-browser-check", "ignore-certificate-errors");

Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Apple iPhone 6");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do it so:

```
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions"));
```

Here was a similar answer [how to disable chrome extension in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049151/how-to-disable-chrome-extension-in-selenium)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fit with:

    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, mobileOptions);

As I need to pass the mobileEmulation value along with the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use [Selenium_Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles)

The Repository allows you to create a webdriver with specific device profiles.

### Profile example:

```
{
  "device":{
      "mobile": false,
      "model": "modelName",
      "language": "de-CH,de;q=0.9",
      "touch_device": true,
      "maxtouchpoints": 5,
      "hardware_accel": false,
      "emulation": {"width": 384, "height": 700, "deviceScaleFactor": 10,
        "screenOrientation": {"type": "portraitPrimary", "angle": 0}},
      "agent_override": {
                "platform": "Win32",
                "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                "userAgentMetadata": {
                    "brands": [{"brand":"Google Chrome","version":"107"},
                              {"brand":"Chromium","version":"107"},
                              {"brand":"Not=A?Brand","version":"24"}],
                    "fullVersionList": [{"brand":"Google Chrome","version":"107.0.5304.88"},
                                        {"brand":"Chromium","version":"107.0.5304.88"},
                                        {"brand":"Not=A?Brand","version":"24.0.0.0"}],
                    "fullVersion": "107.0.5304.88",
                    "platform": "Windows",
                    "platformVersion":"10.0.0",
                    "architecture": "x86",
                    "model": "modelName",
                    "mobile": true,
                    "bitness": "64",
                    "wow64": false}
    }},
  "browser": {
      "sandbox": true, "inkognito": true,"headless":false, "proxy": null, "darkmode": true,
      "pointer_as_touch": false, "mobile_view":  false, "app": false, "touch_events": true,
      "window_size": {"x": 400, "y": 400}
    },
  "chromeoptions": {"arguments": ["--my-argument=value", ..], "capabilities": [["cap_name", "cap_value"], ..]},
  "cdp_cmd": [["name", "value"], ..],
  "evaluate_on_new_document": "my_js_script",
  "plugins": {
      "selenium-wire": false,
      "modheader":"[{\"headers\":[{\"enabled\":true,\"name\":\"google\",\"value\":\"\\\"x\\\"\"}],\"shortTitle\":\"1\",\"title\":\"Profile 1\",\"version\":2}]",
      "stealth": false,
      "buster": false
    }
}
```

It's undetected by Cloudfare, Google..

Changing or adding headers is also supported.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).