# How to set more than one desired capabilities in Selenium using Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to launch chrome in mobile emulation mode and also wanted to set user agent before launch happens. I have found ways to do this one at a time but unable to do it both for same instance of chrome.
Following is my code:

```
String useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1\\; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36 WFBTesting";
    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");
    Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--user-agent="+useragent);
    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");


    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    //capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,(chromeOptions));
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);


    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

In above code I can either pass options or chromeOptions in "capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,**options**);" but if write two setCapability methods one with options and other with chromeOptions, only one of them is in effect for the launched chrome session and not both. Kindly suggest the best way to set both the capabilities and launch the chrome session.

**EDIT**
As suggested I tried following:
Thanks @Cyildirim for your response again. I used following code for my script this time:

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");
        Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromeOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1\\; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36 WFBTesting","test-type","allow-running-insecure-content"));
        chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,(chromeOptions));
```

But even using above I cannot get the user profile to set correctly. Only mobile emulation capability is getting set. Can you correct me if I am writing useragent incorrectly in Array? Or any other suggestion to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try set both of them ?

```
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,chromeOptions);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
```

Comment: Hello @Cyildirim, yes I did try that and what happens is, it'll only set Desired Capability once to either mobile emulation mode or user agent and skip the other one. If you see my code, I already commented one capabilities.setCapability statement. So yes I did tried it and no it didn't work.

Comment: I found your soultion here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612157/adding-arguments-to-chromedriver-mobile-emulation-java . Actualy has created chrome options as alternative of Map. You can handle your case this way.

Comment: Thanks @Cyildirim for your response again. Kindly refer to description (I added more information including your suggestion). It is still not working for me.